# How do I check the user email part that will come from Session?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, asp.net-core, session

Using session in my program, I get the e-mail address and make transactions accordingly. If the user is not logged in, I want to return an error, but I cannot check the session information for null. I need help on this.

```
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Session.GetString("userId").ToString()))
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ErrorPage");
            }
            string UserMail = HttpContext.Session.GetString("userId").ToString();
```

Error : [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBh82.png)

Error2: [Error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APSLo.png)

I tried to check the mail from session with if but it didn't work.

Comment: first check session is not null then try to access the session value.

Comment: @SainPradeep same problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not use `ToString()` here, just check for `null`.

```
if (HttpContext.Session.GetString("userId") == null)
{
    return RedirectToAction("ErrorPage");
}
string UserMail = HttpContext.Session.GetString("userId");
```

`ToString()` throws an exception when yo do something like the below.

```
string str = null;
str.ToString();
```